# Convert a sentence to Integer

Tags: c#, .net, string

Assuming i have a string that says

```
string version  = "Version 1.0.2.3"
```

I want to convert this to an integer or number like "1232454982394". 
This should change based on the text i input. 
While one option is to convert to ascii value or unicode, i have to iterate through each character. Wondering if there is an easier way  - like a one line method that can accomplish this.

The below one works.  but i am looking for something better

```
string version = "Version 1.0.2.3";
string finalOutput = "";
foreach (char c in version)
{
    finalOutput = finalOutput + ((int)c).ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(finalOutput);
// Output is 861011141151051111103249464846504651
```

Comment: It almost sounds like you are asking for a hash without using the word hash. Why not use [String.GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx)? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why do you think you need to generate a number from a string to solve it? What kind of number do you want? Why not return 1 for all strings? Or the integer value of the first or last character? It's impossible to answer unless you explain *what* you want and *why*?

Comment: sounds like code golf

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i need to append the number as version for static files. As the version changes, the files will also be appending with versioning. in Reality my Actual version would look something like  "app 01-23.217-beta/rel 4.0-xxxxcompanyName"

Comment: Why not add the version to the file name, why the mangling?

Comment: @kveey that comment has nothing to do with the question. Explain how you want to generate the version number instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The number should be unique for each version. Version 1.0.2.3 and Version1.0.3.2 should have a different numbers. The return value should be a number. Type can be int /long / string. I think Gethashcode should work.   .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I will accept yours as answer if you can respond your comment in answer. thanks

Comment: I see you already have a _Date_ as part of the filename; I would recommend changing the format to the **yyyyMMdd** format for the soul ability for canonical sorting. You could also append _Time_ onto that in **HHmm** format. I did right a version number parsing script to convert to a long akin to IP4 address conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `GetHashCode` method.

```
string version  = "Version 1.0.2.3";
var hashedValue = version.GetHashCode();
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A hash code is a numeric value that is used to insert and identify an
>   object in a hash-based collection such as the
>   Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) class, the Hashtable class, or a type
>   derived from the DictionaryBase class. The GetHashCode method provides
>   this hash code for algorithms that need quick checks of object
>   equality.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Identical strings can result in different hash codes if running on different versions of .NET. And different strings may equally result in the same number, in the event of a hash collision. (Not my vote though.)

Comment: @hvd given the ambiguity of the question and the size of a version string, I don't think it matters. `GetHashCode()` is just *one* implementation. Given the OP wants to append this to a version string though, the tick value at the time of build would be just as useful. Or a short hash of the *file contents*, like Git does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i cannot use build time because we also use CMS, and files could be served from server or CMS. The app version string is the only thing that changes if there is a build or change of files in CMS. idea is to create different version for static files  "www.mysite.com/js.static.js?v=232323" when there is such change.  here "232323" is the Hashcode value of "Version1.02.3" . Can't directly use the string because, in actual -  it has special characters and some part of name that cannot be exposed. Hope that clarifies. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use the Bundling for JS files or version using Current Datetime.

Comment: Not my vote either; but GetHashCode is more broken as an algorithm than MD5 or its predecessors. The documentation from MS says that it is only required to return true if objects are equal, and does not need to return false if they are not. It is a quick algorithm designed for hashtable comparisons, and its collision rate is inversely proportional to object size

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the `GetHashCode` option for this as the Version intervals are going to be different than the Hash intervals

```
string Version1023 = "Version 1.0.2.3";
string Version1024 = "Version 1.0.2.4";
string Version1033 = "Version 1.0.3.3";
string Version1034 = "Version 1.0.3.4";
Console.WriteLine(Version1023 + " => " + Version1023.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(Version1024 + " => " + Version1024.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(Version1033 + " => " + Version1033.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(Version1034 + " => " + Version1034.GetHashCode());

/* =====[ Results ]=====
    Version 1.0.2.3 => -674112888
    Version 1.0.2.4 => -1433627775
    Version 1.0.3.3 => -674112889
    Version 1.0.3.4 => -1433627776
*/
```

What I would recommend, and only if the string is going to remain in the same format, would be to `split` the string and concentrate on the version numerics portion. For a four element version number we can use common scripting which is used for converting IP4 Addresses to `long` addresses. 
Here is a slighty tweaked version to do this split and conversion

```
public static long GetLongFromVersion(string VersionString) {
    string[] VersionSplit = VersionString.Split(` `);
    string VersionNumber = VersionSplit[1];
    string[] VersionBytes;
    double num = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionNumber)) {
        VersionBytes = VersionNumber.Split(`.`);
        for (int i = VersionBytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            num += ((int.Parse(VersionBytes[i]) % 256) * Math.Pow(256, (3 - i)));
        }
    }
    return (long)num;
}
```

And when we use this method to convert the version numbers, the version and result will have intervals that are parallel.

```
string Version1023 = "Version 1.0.2.3";
string Version1024 = "Version 1.0.2.4";
string Version1033 = "Version 1.0.3.3";
string Version1034 = "Version 1.0.3.4";
Console.WriteLine(Version1023 + " => " + GetLongFromVersion(Version1023));
Console.WriteLine(Version1024 + " => " + GetLongFromVersion(Version1024));
Console.WriteLine(Version1033 + " => " + GetLongFromVersion(Version1033));
Console.WriteLine(Version1034 + " => " + GetLongFromVersion(Version1034));

/* =====[ Results ]=====
    Version 1.0.2.3 => 16777731
    Version 1.0.2.4 => 16777732
    Version 1.0.3.3 => 16777987
    Version 1.0.3.4 => 16777988
*/
```

Comment: This wont work  - i have mentioned in one of my comments that the actual value would look something like  "app 01-23.217-beta/rel 4.0-xxxxcompanyName".

Comment: If you can come up with a standard format for how the version value will be delineated you can use that to parse whatever format. The key is to have standards in place. If you should ever need to track actual version numbers this will make it a hell of a lot easier.